# Generate normals for Direct3D 9 Mesh

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, mesh, normals

I'm already know that this possible through using D3DXComputeNormals() method, but I just can't figure out how to use it properly. There is no any tutorials or lessons for doing this. Can someone give me explanation or provide me with useful code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean, "properly"? Are you looking for tutorials on calculating adjacency? If not, the MSDN documentation states it quite well [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172742(v=vs.85).aspx), pass in NULL for the `pAdjacency` parameter.

Comment: The only problem I encountered is that D3DXComputeNormals() needs not LPD3DXMESH, but LPD3DXBASEMESH. What to do?

Comment: ID3DXMesh derives from ID3DXBaseMesh so it should be perfectly ok to pass in ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174069(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The [DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981) library can generate normals which you could use for any version of Direct3D.

```
std::unique_ptr<WaveFrontReader<uint16_t>> mesh( new WaveFrontReader<uint16_t>() );

if ( FAILED( mesh->Load( L"test.obj" ) ) )
   // Error

if ( mesh->hasNormals )
   // Skip next computation

size_t nFaces = mesh->indices.size() / 3;
size_t nVerts = mesh->vertices.size();

std::unique_ptr<XMFLOAT3[]> pos( new XMFLOAT3[ nVerts ] );
for( size_t j = 0; j < nVerts; ++j )
   pos.get()[ j ] = mesh->vertices[ j ].position;

std::unique_ptr<XMFLOAT3[]> normals( new XMFLOAT3[ nVerts ] );
if ( FAILED( ComputeNormals( &mesh->indices.front(), nFaces,
   pos.get(), nVerts, CNORM_DEFAULT, normals.get() ) ) )
   // Error
```

The library and source is on CodePlex, so you can always step into it to see what it's doing, and it is intended as a replacement for the deprecated D3DX library.